# Block user via facebook api

Tags: facebook, api

Is there any Facebook API which will block user(programaticaly) from a third party web application

Let's assume someone(User_1) is logged in his Facebook account and then he opens my website(example.com) in a new tab. There is a block_user button on my website. if User_1 clicks the block_user button in my application, he adds another user(User_2) to User_1's blacklist. So User_2 becomes blocked for User_1.
My question is: Is it possible to do it via Facebook API. I could not find any information about it in the documentation.

Comment: No there is no API to block people on Facebook